In Azure DevOps, how to setup a task to update my database with Entity Framework code first?
In Azure DevOps, in Continuous Deployment, in Release pipelines, I do a deployment of a classic MVC ISS application on two stages: staging then production.

This classic app also connect to a classic SQL server. I use Entity Framework 6 with code first. I usa database migration and database update ti maintain my database. I have a database for staging and one for production. Classic again.
I would like to update my database during the Release deployment. How can I do that?
I know how to update from the Nuget Package console. I also know how to update from command line on my local computer, and I added script, command line, task to run the command line of the update on my staging environment.

On deployment I get an error:
2024-11-25T09:42:55.3022423Z ##[section]Starting: Database Update (1)
2024-11-25T09:42:55.3139346Z ==============================================================================
2024-11-25T09:42:55.3139845Z Task         : Command line
2024-11-25T09:42:55.3140335Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2024-11-25T09:42:55.3140807Z Version      : 2.246.1
2024-11-25T09:42:55.3141145Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2024-11-25T09:42:55.3141653Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2024-11-25T09:42:55.3142254Z ==============================================================================
2024-11-25T09:42:56.4933942Z Generating script.
2024-11-25T09:42:56.5056124Z Script contents: shell
2024-11-25T09:42:56.5066756Z dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
2024-11-25T09:42:56.5515592Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2024-11-25T09:42:56.5933019Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\600cdcc8-d17f-4a1b-a267-9775bbe965ed.cmd""
2024-11-25T09:42:56.6252157Z The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
2024-11-25T09:42:56.6252927Z   * You intended to execute a .NET application:
2024-11-25T09:42:56.6253474Z       The application 'tool' does not exist.
2024-11-25T09:42:56.6254040Z   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
2024-11-25T09:42:56.6254543Z       No .NET SDKs were found.
2024-11-25T09:42:56.6254948Z 
2024-11-25T09:42:56.6255327Z Download a .NET SDK:
2024-11-25T09:42:56.6255772Z https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
2024-11-25T09:42:56.6255994Z 
2024-11-25T09:42:56.6256364Z Learn about SDK resolution:
2024-11-25T09:42:56.6256840Z https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
2024-11-25T09:42:56.7657771Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '-2147450735'.
2024-11-25T09:42:56.8097854Z ##[section]Finishing: Install DotNet Entity Framework

What should I add in my script to make sure the system recognize the dotnet tool install instruction?

From your screenshot, you are using deployment group(On-Prem Machine) in release pipeline. Can you confirm if the required .NET SDK is installed on the agent machine?

It is not as neither winget / dotnet install are compatible with my version of Windows. But I can run my project under IIS installed on the same machine. (IIS 7.5 with .NET 4.7.2)

Can you try to refer to my answer and add the Use Dot Net task in the Release Pipeline and set the dotnet version? Then you can check if pipeline can run the dotnet tool install command as expected


I can run my project under IIS installed on the same machine. (IIS 7.5 with .NET 4.7.2)  Can you share some details about how you run the project on your local machine? Are you running the same command as release pipeline?

